# System.DmlException: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

I am getting the below error:

Errors

> Treatment Code: bad value for restricted picklist field: 95972
>   System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for
>   restricted picklist field: 95972: [Treatment_Code__c]

I checked the value is in the picklist but still getting error.

Code:

VF:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Treatment Code">
    <apex:selectList label="TCode" value="{!rev1.Treatment_Code__c}" size="1" multiselect="false">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:column>
```

Class:

```
public class TreatmentCodeCreationController{ 
    public Id CurrentPageId{get; set;}
    public List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c> TreatmentCodeList{get; set;} 
    public List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c> insertTrtCodeSection;
    public List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c> deleteTrtCodeSection;
    public HEMA_Treatment_Code__c TreatmentCodeData;
    public List<Case> caseRec = new List<Case>();
    public boolean isEdit{get; set;}
    public boolean isError {get;set;} // For capturing error message 
    public Integer rowNum{get;set;}    
    Id TRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.HEMA_Treatment_Code__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('HEMA Treatment Code').RecordTypeId;
    public string procedureTypeCase{get; set;}
    public String selectedValue{get;set; }

    // Constructor
    public TreatmentCodeCreationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){      
        CurrentPageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
        caseRec = [Select Id, HEMA_Procedure__c From Case Where id =:CurrentPageId];
        TreatmentCodeList = [Select Id,Treatment_Code__c,Units__c,Name,Procedure__c,Case__r.HEMA_Procedure__c,Case_Procedure_Type__c From HEMA_Treatment_Code__c Where Case__c =:CurrentPageId];
        procedureTypeCase = caseRec[0].HEMA_Procedure__c;
        isEdit = false;
        isError = false;
        if(TreatmentCodeList.size() == 0){
            isEdit = true;
            for (Integer idx=0; idx<8; idx++){
                addrow();
            }
        }        
    }

    // Picklist

    public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions(){ 
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
      options.add(new SelectOption('','Select one'));
      for(TreatmentCodes__c tc : TreatmentCodes__c.getAll().values()){
        if(tc.Procedure__c == procedureTypeCase){
            options.add(new SelectOption(tc.Treatment_Code__c.trim(), tc.Treatment_Code__c.trim()));
        }         
      }
      return options;
    }

    // Edit Method
    public void btnEdit(){
        isEdit = true;
    }        

    //Add row
    public void addrow()
    {        
        TreatmentCodeData = new HEMA_Treatment_Code__c();
        TreatmentCodeData.RecordTypeId = TRecordTypeId;
        TreatmentCodeData.Case__c = CurrentPageId;
        TreatmentCodeList.add(TreatmentCodeData);        
    }

    // Save Method
    public PageReference btnSave(){
        try{ 
            insertTrtCodeSection = new List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c>();
            deleteTrtCodeSection = new List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c>();
            List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c> finalListTrtCodeSection = new List<HEMA_Treatment_Code__c>();

            isError = false;
            isEdit = false;
            system.debug('**InsertList--->'+TreatmentCodeList);        
            for(HEMA_Treatment_Code__c rv: TreatmentCodeList){
                if(String.isBlank(rv.Treatment_Code__c)){
                    deleteTrtCodeSection.add(rv);
                }
                else{                  
                    insertTrtCodeSection.add(rv);
                }                                
            }            

            if(!insertTrtCodeSection.isEmpty() && insertTrtCodeSection != null){                
                Upsert insertTrtCodeSection;
            }
            if(!deleteTrtCodeSection.isEmpty() && deleteTrtCodeSection != null){
                for(HEMA_Treatment_Code__c rvd: deleteTrtCodeSection){
                    if(rvd.Id != null){
                        finalListTrtCodeSection.add(rvd);
                    }
                }
                if(!finalListTrtCodeSection.isEmpty() && finalListTrtCodeSection != null){
                    Delete finalListTrtCodeSection;
                }                                
            }

            PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/'+CurrentPageId);
            retURL.setRedirect(true);
            return retURL;
        } 
        catch(exception e){
        system.debug('***exception***'+e);
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,string.valueof(e));
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            isError = true;
            isEdit= true;
            return null;
        }   
    }

    // Cancel Method
    public PageReference btnkcancel()
    {
        isEdit = false;
        return null;
    }        
}
```

Please help me. Attached are the screen shot of VF page and actual picklist values:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Additionally check that the value is available for the set recordtype

Comment: yes, if that is not added in the recordtype then you will get this error.

Comment: Its in the record type.. I checked

Comment: @shashankgupta - Remove all VF and apex code from the equation. Use dev console and try to insert a record just like you think the VF/Apex code is inserting. Troubleshoot there first. If it fails you know it is due to a misunderstanding on your part and either the Item is not available to the recordtype, user, or something. If it works, debug what you are inserting in your code and see if any differences.